# Как содержимое курсора записать в JSONB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Курсор возвращает rows из pg_variables.

Каким образом записать их в JSONB?

Postgres 9.6

Comment: небольшое пояснение на основе примера помогло бы вопросу...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обычной таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE a (a_id int PRIMARY KEY, a text);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar');

TABLE a;

DO $$
DECLARE 
r record;
j jsonb;

BEGIN

FOR r IN SELECT * FROM a
LOOP 

  SELECT row_to_json(r) INTO j;
  RAISE info '%', j;

END LOOP;

END
$$
```

Для курсора

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
r record;
j jsonb;
prc_curs refcursor;

BEGIN

  prc_curs = "Функция, которая возвращает курсор"(параметры);

  LOOP
  FETCH prc_curs INTO r;
  exit WHEN NOT FOUND;

  --RAISE info '%', row_to_json(r)::jsonb;--r;

  j = row_to_json(r)::jsonb;

  j = jsonb_set(j, '{code}', '123', false); -- Так можно обновить значение

  j = jsonb_set(j, '{name}', '"I"', true); -- Так добавить

  -- RAISE NOTICE '%', j;

  PERFORM "Функция, которая принимает JSONB"(j);


  END LOOP;

END
$$
```